# PHP and PDO prepared statments - Column not found

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with a "unknown" column.
This is the error I get back in firebug.

> ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'admin' in 'where clause'UPDATE users SET session_key = 1234567890 WHERE username = 'admin'

this is the parameters and call statement

> $table = 'users';
>
> $fields_vals = array( 'session_key' => $session_key );
>
> $where = array('username' => $username);
>
> $dbResult = $this->DB->sql_update($fields_vals, $table, $where);

```
/*
     * UPDATE
     * $data -> assoc array containing (field => value) to be UPDATED.
     * $where -> Where clause (only a single argument)
     * $table -> to be updated
*/

 public function sql_update($fieldsVals, $table, $where)
    {
        try {
            //Values to be updated in in a assoc array
            //Extract values and fields and concatenate with '=' ( field = value )
            $upd_string = '';
            foreach($fieldsVals as $name => $value){
                $upd_string .= $name .' = :'. $name .' ,';
            }
            //Trim last comma that was appended
            $upd_string = rtrim($upd_string, ',');

            // Formulate the where clause
            $where_str = '';
            foreach($where as $wName => $wValue){
                $where_str .= "$wName = $wValue";
            }



              //Set Query
                //$query = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$upd_string} WHERE $where_str";

              // THIS IS WHERE I EXPLICITLY RAN THE QUERY, BUT GOT EXACTLY THE SAME ERROR.
                $query = "UPDATE users SET session_key = 1234567890 WHERE username = 'admin'";
                $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

            //Exec
            foreach($fieldsVals as $k => &$v){
                $stmt->bindParam(":{$k}", $v);
            }
            $stmt->execute();
            return true;

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Here is proof that the column does exist.
[image]

**PLEASE NOTE ->   where username = 'admin'**

Comment: please give the datatype of those columns?

Comment: Have you tried to run this query in PhpMyAdmin? Have you used for sure `'` before and after word `admin` ?

Comment: Maybe problem with wrong quotes, be sure that you are using     '

Comment: Why do you use 1234567890 as an int when it's indeed a varchar?

Comment: Yes works perfect in phpMyAdmin.
and the 1234567890 -> just a test query to try and force it. Prepared statment did not work as-well

Comment: You're preparing your field values just fine, but your code produces a WHERE clause of "WHERE username = admin", and unlike with the field values, there's no attempt to bind the your value ("admin") to a parameter. Why are you expecting this to work?

Comment: @MattGibson- because Im new to PHP thats why. but point taken and will try a different approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing your `WHERE` attribute in as a prepared variable:

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET session_key = 1234567890 WHERE username = :username";
$fieldsVals[":username"] = "admin";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
            $where_str .= "$wName = '$wValue'";
```

Otherwise your query comes as "WHERE username = admin"

Comment: That's correct but not a good advice. He says he is preparing the statements.

Comment: Ive changed it to '$where_str .= "$wName = \"$wValue\"";' but still get the same thing.... thnx for the suggestion

Comment: @DanFromGermany But he's using prepared statments only for part of query not for where clause

Comment: @morne nel, not like that, use single quotes, just like I showed

Comment: @Limiter - okay done that... ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'admin' in 'where clause'UPDATE users SET session_key = ":session_key"  WHERE username = 'admin'

Comment: @mornenel the error is coming from a different part of your script obvisouly! Also dont put quotes arround bind param: `= :session_key` instead of `= ":session_key"`. Man this guessing... Learn about MySQL then try again.

Answer (score 1):

The correct usage would be:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare('UPDATE users SET session_key = :session WHERE username = :username');
$stmt->bindParam(':session', session_id(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Then execute.

I think your variable `$fieldsVals` is wrong due to the foreach's you do. Maybe you switching key und val by accident, resulting in `WHERE admin=username`.

Update:

@MarcinNabiałek is right of course you are missing quotes.

**But it seems like the error is coming from a different part of the script.**

Comment: No, that's not that. He has `$where_str .= "$wName = $wValue";` what generates `username=admin` and not `username='admin'`. He doesn't use prepared statement for this part of query

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek Why not prepare all variables? `WHERE` clause might be the most critical part, he should bind it.

Comment: of course he should do it for all variables but this way he should change the whole code to generate correct ouutput

Comment: @DanFromGermany -> got this back -> Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference.   Its complaining about the session_id(). will pass it through a variable though and let you know

Answer (score 1):

What you should do to use prepared statements for the whole query, so you should change your function from the current one into:

```
function sql_update($fieldsVals, $table, $where)
{

    //Values to be updated in in a assoc array
    //Extract values and fields and concatenate with '=' ( field = value )
    $upd_string = '';
    foreach ($fieldsVals as $name => $value) {
        $upd_string .= $name . ' = :set_' . $name . ' ,';
    }
    //Trim last comma that was appended
    $upd_string = rtrim($upd_string, ',');

    // Formulate the where clause
    $where_str = '';
    foreach ($where as $wName => $wValue) {
        $where_str .= $wName . ' = :wh_' . $wName . ' ,';

    }
    //Trim last comma that was appended
    $where_str = rtrim($where_str, ',');


    //Set Query
    $query = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$upd_string} WHERE $where_str";


    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    //Exec
    foreach ($fieldsVals as $k => &$v) {
        $stmt->bindParam(":set_{$k}", $v);
    }
    foreach ($where as $k => &$v) {
        $stmt->bindParam(":wh_{$k}", $v);
    }
    $stmt->execute();
    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't use `'` in your query in PHP. Either you don't use it or use other symbol that look similar.

If I run in phpmyAdmin query:

```
UPDATE users SET session_key = 1234567890 WHERE username = admin
```

I also get error message:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'admin' in 'where clause'
```

but when I have

```
UPDATE users SET session_key = 1234567890 WHERE username = 'admin'
```

it works fine

In your code you should definitelly change:

```
$where_str .= "$wName = $wValue";
```

into

```
$where_str .= "$wName = '$wValue'";
```

Comment: Look at his code: `$query = "UPDATE users SET session_key = 1234567890 WHERE username = 'admin'";` All his quotes are correctly used.

Comment: I see it but I'm not 100% sure he really put `'` signs in his test script

Answer (score 0):

`session_key` is a varchar

You have to use the query like the below,

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET session_key = '1234567890' WHERE username = 'admin'";
```

Answer (score -4):

column `admin` doesn't exist! column `administrator` exists though.

I don't see any admin column in your mysql table in the screenshot that you provided.

You can simply change the name of the `administrator` column in your mysql table to `admin` and everything will work.

Comment: He's not trying to pass in `admin` as a column, he has it in his `WHERE` statement.

Comment: Dont try to say that you are right again with answer. Your answer is wrong.

Comment: @VinothBabu, "again"? what do you mean "again"? have we had a debate about any of my answers before, you and i?!